# Take your hands out "of / from" your pockets

Tags: prepositions, american-english, british-english

Which is proper:

> Take your hands out **of** your pockets.
>
> Take your hands out **from** your pockets.

Is there any difference in American English and British English?

P.S. Also reading the comments - is there a preffered form for singular or plural, or they are the same?

Comment: Both are possible, but where I'm from, NYC (i.e. I speak American English), the strong preference would be for *of*. The *from* sounds British, or old-fashioned, or stuffy, or something.

Comment: The *of* version is idiomatic, as confirmed by [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+your+pocket%2Cout+from+your+pocket&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20your%20pocket%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I also think so - that both are possible, but I was not sure how to differentiate the use. Can you answer so I can approve.

Comment: @Lawrence: Actually, your NGram is for *singular* "pocket", which I'd guess mainly reflects the more figurative usage of *It's not like you paid for it out of your own pocket*. But the idiomatic preference is the same for OP's "literal" context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do the Brits ever say things like "take your hand out *from* the cookie jar"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's the same for the [plural version](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+your+pockets%2Cout+from+your+pockets&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20your%20pockets%3B%2Cc0) - I checked but must have not pasted it into the comment. For a more [persuasive comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+your%2Cout+from+your&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20your%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20from%20your%3B%2Cc0), drop *pocket[s]* altogether.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov I just saw your comment (you can ping individual users using the "@" convention). Answering now.

Comment: 10x @Lawrence, I know that ("@"). I don't understand it there a difference between `pocket` and `pockets` - I mean is there a preffed form for plural and singular?

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov Oh. Should I delete my answer? I thought your earlier comment was intended for me. As for singular or plural, it just depends on whether the hands are in one pocket or two. My first comment linked to the wrong Ngram for your question; sorry about that.

Comment: No, your answer is ok, @Lawrence. I just want to be sure that I use it properly.

Comment: Include in your question the research you’ve done. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions would be well understood, but "Take your hands out *of* your pockets" is idiomatic based on [Ngram's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out%20of%20your%20pockets%2Cout%20from%20your%20pockets&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20your%20pockets%3B%2Cc0) corpus.

Regarding plurality, if the hands were initially in a single pocket, use the singular, *pocket*. If they were in separate pockets, use the plural, *pockets*.